# Multiple Between Dates Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between

I have this dataset that is structured more or less like the following:

| Product | Sales Value | Sales Qty | Sales Date | Period 1 start | Period 1 end | Period 2 start | Period 2 end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 6 | 2 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 |
| YYY | 10 | 3 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 |
| XXX | 3 | 1 | 2021-05-23 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 |
| XXX | 6 | 2 | 2021-05-24 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 |

I would like to sum the columns "sales value" and "sales quantity" and create 4 more columns called "Period 1 Sales", "Period 1 Qty", "Period 2 Sales", and "Period 2 Qty".

For example, with the data above, I would get four new columns while rows would be grouped by product:

| Product | Period 1 start | Period 1 end | Period 2 start | Period 2 end | Period 1 Sales Value | Period 1 Sales Qty | Period 2 Sales Value | Period 2 Sales Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 3 |
| YYY | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-06-01 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 3 |

I'm using SQL Server and right now I am pretty much stuck.

So far I managed to Cross Join my calendar table and sales table to get the table described in the first matrix.

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/ask

Comment: @DaleK, sorry for the imprecise question. I added my desired output to the question. As for what I tried, I basically tried to Inner Join my calendar table and my sales table several times to get different Period start / end sales dates. It did not really work though.

Comment: We need to see what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

The following provides your desired results, with the exception of your value for YYY where in your sample data the values are in period1 not period 2.

```
select Product,
    Period1start, Period1end, Period1start, Period2end,
    Sum(P1sales) Period1Sales, Sum(P1Qty) Period1Qty, 
    Sum(P2sales) Period2Sales, Sum(P2Qty) Period2Qty
from t
cross apply(values(case when SalesDate between Period1start and Period1end then SalesValue else 0 end)  )p1s(P1sales)
cross apply(values(case when SalesDate between Period1start and Period1end then SalesQty else 0 end)    )p1q(P1Qty)
cross apply(values(case when SalesDate between Period2start and Period2end then SalesValue else 0 end)  )p2s(P2sales)
cross apply(values(case when SalesDate between Period2start and Period2end then SalesQty else 0 end)    )p2q(P2Qty)
group by product, Period1start, Period1end, Period1start, Period2end
```

See [example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9fe4d7417330f0fda31a3a204980c873)